# In Holoviz Panel, how to select a file and make its contents available for interactive graphs?

Tags: panel, holoviz, holoviz-panel

I want to replicate this example from the documentation of Holoviz Panel: https://panel-gallery.pyviz.demo.anaconda.com/hvplot_explorer. That is, I want to:

- Have a dropdown menu in which I can select multiple data sources.
- Have an upload button such that I can add my own data source. This uploaded source should also be added to the dropdown.
- Have a plot that shows the data selected in the dropdown menu.

Currently I have this:

```
import pandas as pd
import panel as pn

inputFile = pn.widgets.FileInput(accept=".csv")
```

I can access the input file in VS Code (in my jupyter notebook), but how do I update the dashboard I am building with this data?

Comment: You should load data from file that is uploaded. Alternatively, you can check Mercury framework for buiding UI from notebooks https://github.com/mljar/mercury - it has File widget as well https://runmercury.com/docs/input-widgets/file/